# Knockout: How to do a two-way binding for two number inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I just recently picked up KO and want to do something similar to the following.

There are two inputs and they change one another.

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: var1" type="text">
<input data-bind-"value: var2" type="text">
```

Script:

```
function DataViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.price = 5;
        self.var1 = ko.observable(0);
        self.var2 = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                if(self.var1() <= 0) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return (self.var1 - 1) / self.price;
            },
            write: function (value) {
                self.var1((Number(value) + 1) * self.price); 
                // Value = 7.8, output is 44 for var1,
                // var2 changes to 8.6. Desired is 40 for var1 and 7.8 for var2.
            },
            owner: self
        });
    }
ko.applyBindings(new DataViewModel());
```

When 40 is inputed into var1, var2 shows 7.8. But when 7.8 is inputed into var2, var1 updates to 44 instead of 40 and the var2 changes to 8.6.

I want var2 to remain what was inputed instead of undergoing the read function.

http://jsfiddle.net/tyq7ejdh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is incorrect

```
   write: function (value) {
                self.var1((value+1) * self.price);
            },
```

Try updating like this

```
   write: function (value) {
                self.var1((value * self.price) + 1);
            },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyq7ejdh/1/)

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong with javascript. I want the output to be 40 in the write function when 7 is inputed. So (7+1) * 5. I'm guessing it is distributing the five to the seven and one and concatenating them like strings? That would be the only explanation for an output of 355.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here?
when I input 2 into var1, it displays 0.2 for var2, when I input 5 into var 1 it displays 0.8 into var 2, and same case if I input 0.2 into var2 it displays 2 in var. isn't it the same what you're looking for?

Comment: I have confused myself now. What I originally wanted was the following: Input 40 into var1, output 7.8 for var2. Input 7.8 into var2, output 40 for var1 with var2 not changing. When I input 7.8, it will output var1 = 44 and var2 = 8.6.

Comment: Hey, my code is exactly same as you're looking for, check fiddle, When you input 40 in var1, var2 will be 7.8 or when you input 7.8 in var2, var1 will be 40 with no change in var2

Comment: It was all about the algebra! Thanks Moksh Shah, took me awhile to see where I messed up!